# issue while fetch data from nested json array

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I am fetch `JSON` data from API and I am getting response successfully but there are some issue for me that how to get direct value without key first let me show you my response

**Reponse**

```
{
  "message": "Notification Sent Successfully.",
  "success": "1",
  "message_list": [
    {
      "+919722552298": [
        {
          "body": "Sent from your Twilio trial account - This is test message by purvesh",
          "from": "",
          "sid": "",
          "status": "sent",
          "date_updated": "Mon, 01 Jul 2019 12:58:49 +0000",
          "date_sent": "Mon, 01 Jul 2019 12:58:49 +0000",
          "date_created": "Mon, 01 Jul 2019 12:58:49 +0000",
          "to": ""
        },
        {
          "body": "Sent from your Twilio trial account - This is test message by purvesh",
          "from": "",
          "sid": "",
          "status": "sent",
          "date_updated": "Sat, 29 Jun 2019 09:36:07 +0000",
          "date_sent": "Sat, 29 Jun 2019 09:36:07 +0000",
          "date_created": "Sat, 29 Jun 2019 09:36:07 +0000",
          "to": ""
        },
        {
          "body": "Sent from your Twilio trial account - This is test message by purvesh",
          "from": "",
          "sid": "",
          "status": "sent",
          "date_updated": "Sat, 29 Jun 2019 09:35:18 +0000",
          "date_sent": "Sat, 29 Jun 2019 09:35:18 +0000",
          "date_created": "Sat, 29 Jun 2019 09:35:18 +0000",
          "to": ""
        },
        {
          "body": "Sent from your Twilio trial account - This is a test message...",
          "from": "",
          "sid": "",
          "status": "sent",
          "date_updated": "Sat, 29 Jun 2019 05:56:43 +0000",
          "date_sent": "Sat, 29 Jun 2019 05:56:43 +0000",
          "date_created": "Sat, 29 Jun 2019 05:56:43 +0000",
          "to": ""
        },
        {
          "body": "Sent from your Twilio trial account - This is a test...",
          "from": "",
          "sid": "",
          "status": "sent",
          "date_sent": "Thu, 27 Jun 2019 11:52:44 +0000",
          "date_created": "Thu, 27 Jun 2019 11:52:43 +0000",
          "date_updated": "Thu, 27 Jun 2019 11:52:44 +0000",
          "to": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "+61459036405": [
        {
          "body": "Sent from your Twilio trial account - Thanks for the message. Configure your number's SMS URL to change this message.Reply HELP for help.Reply STOP to unsubscribe.Msg&Data rates may apply.",
          "from": "",
          "sid": "",
          "status": "delivered",
          "date_sent": "Sat, 29 Jun 2019 06:25:33 +0000",
          "date_created": "Sat, 29 Jun 2019 06:25:33 +0000",
          "date_updated": "Sat, 29 Jun 2019 06:25:35 +0000",
          "to": ""
        },
        {
          "body": "Hello Ron ",
          "from": "",
          "sid": "",
          "status": "received",
          "date_sent": "Sat, 29 Jun 2019 06:25:33 +0000",
          "date_created": "Sat, 29 Jun 2019 06:25:33 +0000",
          "date_updated": "Sat, 29 Jun 2019 06:25:33 +0000",
          "to": ""
        },
        {
          "body": "Sent from your Twilio trial account - This is a test message...",
          "from": "",
          "sid": "",
          "date_updated": "Sat, 29 Jun 2019 06:08:42 +0000",
          "date_created": "Sat, 29 Jun 2019 06:08:42 +0000",
          "status": "sent",
          "date_sent": "Sat, 29 Jun 2019 06:08:42 +0000",
          "to": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "+918733009842": [
        {
          "body": "Sent from your Twilio trial account - This is a test...",
          "from": "",
          "sid": "",
          "date_updated": "Thu, 27 Jun 2019 12:32:45 +0000",
          "date_created": "Thu, 27 Jun 2019 12:32:45 +0000",
          "status": "sent",
          "date_sent": "Thu, 27 Jun 2019 12:32:45 +0000",
          "to": ""
        },
        {
          "body": "Sent from your Twilio trial account - This is a test...",
          "from": "",
          "sid": "",
          "status": "sent",
          "date_created": "Thu, 27 Jun 2019 12:25:37 +0000",
          "date_updated": "Thu, 27 Jun 2019 12:25:37 +0000",
          "date_sent": "Thu, 27 Jun 2019 12:25:37 +0000",
          "to": ""
        },
        {
          "body": "Sent from your Twilio trial account - This is a test...",
          "from": "",
          "sid": "",
          "status": "sent",
          "date_created": "Thu, 27 Jun 2019 12:07:04 +0000",
          "date_updated": "Thu, 27 Jun 2019 12:07:04 +0000",
          "date_sent": "Thu, 27 Jun 2019 12:07:04 +0000",
          "to": ""
        },
        {
          "body": "Sent from your Twilio trial account - This is a test...",
          "from": "",
          "sid": "",
          "status": "sent",
          "date_created": "Thu, 27 Jun 2019 12:01:55 +0000",
          "date_updated": "Thu, 27 Jun 2019 12:01:55 +0000",
          "date_sent": "Thu, 27 Jun 2019 12:01:55 +0000",
          "to": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

here is my response and now I will show you I am getting data of `message_list` array successfully but issue is how to get phone number which is main array as you show in my response I want numbers list which is array in side message list array

```
func messageListAPI(){

    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
    let uid = "u_id"
    let acTkn = "acc_tkn"
    let u_ID = preferences.object(forKey: uid)
    let A_Token = preferences.object(forKey: acTkn)

    let params = ["user_id": u_ID!,"access_token": A_Token!,"twilio_number": "+13344313181"]
    // print(params)
    Alamofire.request(messagelist, method: .post, parameters: params).responseJSON(completionHandler: {(response) in
        switch response.result{
        case.success(let value):
            let json  = JSON(value)
            print(json)
            let message = json["message"].stringValue
            let success = json["success"].stringValue
            let data = json["message_list"]
            let model = ResponseModel(message: message, success: success, messageList: data) // Here i am getting error
        case.failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    })
}
```

Here is my API call method I am getting `message_list` successfully can any one help me to get numbers list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create these models for response:

```
/// Main response model
struct ResponseModel: Codable {
    let message: String
    let success: String
    let messageList: [[String: [MessageList]]]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case message, success
        case messageList = "message_list"
    }
}

/// MessageList Model
struct MessageList: Codable {
    let body: String
    let from: String
    let sid: String
    let status: Status
    let dateSent: String
    let dateCreated
    let dateUpdated
    let to: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case body, from, sid, status
        case dateSent = "date_sent"
        case dateCreated = "date_created"
        case dateUpdated = "date_updated"
        case to
    }
}

/// For status field
enum Status: String, Codable {
    case delivered = "delivered"
    case received = "received"
    case sent = "sent"
}
```

---

You can use these models with **Alamofire**

```
/// YOU MUST CHANGE 'ResponseType' with the real type of response

func messageListAPI(_ completion: @escaping (ResponseType) -> Void) {
    let urlString = "http://yourUrl"
    Alamofire.request(urlString).response { response in
        guard let data = response.data else { return }
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let response: ResponseType = try decoder.decode(ResponseModel.self, from: data)
            let numberList = response.messageList.compactMap({ $0.keys })
            print("my numberList -> \(numberList)")
            completion(response)

        } catch let error {
            print(error)
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

**USAGE:**

```
messageListAPI { response in
    /// If response is nil it's means error appear.
    /// Otherwise it is successful
    print(response)
}
```

---

You can use **URLSession** also

```
guard let yourUrl = URL(string: "https://myUrl") else { return }
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: yourUrl) { (data, response , error) in      
    guard let data = data else { return }
    do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let data = try decoder.decode(ResponseModel.self, from: data)
        print(data)
    } catch let error {
        print("Err", error)
    }
}.resume()
```

---

You can use these models for parse response `JSON`. And then you can get number list like that:

```
let numberList = ResponseModel.messageList.compactMap({ $0.keys })
```

If you have any question about use Codable models for API response please ask immediately.

Enjoy.

Comment: Yes i understand but with this models how can i able to get numbers list with is inside message_list array

Comment: You can use this line -> `let numberList = ResponseModel.messageList.compactMap({ $0.keys })` **ResponseModel is your response from API**

Comment: How to append data in Response Model from api response please tell me

Comment: please check i have update API call method code i append data as you show in my code but i am getting error `Cannot convert value of type 'JSON' to expected argument type '[[String : [MessageList]]]'` because data in in json formate

Comment: Hi again @VishalParmar. Please check my edit. You can customize `Alamofire` or `URLSession` requests for according to your requests. I hope this works. Enjoy.

Comment: Okay i am trying thanks for help if any query then i will tell you

Comment: Hello this solution work for me thanks and i am getting data like this `my numberList -> [Dictionary.Keys(["+919722552298"]), Dictionary.Keys(["+61459036405"]), Dictionary.Keys(["+918733009842"])]` but how to populate this in tableview please help me

Comment: @VishalParmar Please open another question for populate to tableViewCell

Comment: @Vicaren please refer link i have asked another question for populate in tableview here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56963188/after-getting-json-data-from-api-populate-in-tableview-issue

Answer (score 0):

Just paste your json response get your model from https://app.quicktype.io/

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: yourURL) { (data, resonse, err) in
            if err == nil{

            }else{
                do{
                    let model = JSONDecoder().decode(YourModel.self, from: data!)
                }catch(let decodeErr){
                    print(decodeErr)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
```

Answer (score -1):

Since message list is an array, you could possibly try doing this-

```
let data = json["message_list"]

for (index, item) in data.enumerated() {
    print(item[index])
}
```

Comment: The For Loop Syntax is different in Swift also there is no console.log

Comment: My answer is just a model, you can convert that in whatever language you are using. The answer emphasizes on a possible way of accessing 'data' variable

Comment: Yes but when i convert it into swift i am getting error `Value of type 'JSON' has no member 'length'`

Comment: Have some respect for the question asked and respond with code in the same programming language.

Comment: Make one thing sure that when you do "var data = json['message_list']" what data you are getting? If you are getting objects then you will be able to access

Comment: i am getting whole data which is inside message_list